# Lie algebra action obtained from Lie group action

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Suppose that $G, H$ are Lie groups and $\mathfrak{g}$ the Lie algebra of $G$. Suppose that there is a Lie group action $G \times H \to H$. Is there a natural $\mathfrak{g}$ action on $C^{\infty}(H)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, by the vector fields of the associated Lie algebra action on $H$.